# How to scale Oracle on AWS ( or any Cloud)?

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, cloud, scalability

How to scale Oracle on the cloud ( without using Amazon AWS RDS Oracle) ?

Oracle RAC is not an option, as SAN ( or any high throughput shared storage) is not provided by any cloud vendor.

I am more interested in knowing the replication technologies available.

PS: Any Oracle version that works is good enough. The scale is to achieve more throughput for more number of users.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Updated:**

The best replication technology is Oracle's GoldenGate but it comes with a significant price tag. It has real-time replication capabilities, even on heterogeneous databases. Next best solution would be Oracle Data Integrator which has change data capture capabilities. Apart from these which come form Oracle, Talend has an integration tool with change data capture capabilities. If neither of these is an option, you can start developing an own replication solution (not advisable) using Oracle Streams or an Apache Kafka cluster.

---

Without knowing too much about your license, constraints and DB version (I'm assuming 11g), here are the options:

- scale up by adding more resources (memory, CPU etc.) but this might translate to additional licensing costs (depending on the license you already have)
- scale out by adding additional database instances or database clusters and deploy a load balancer in front of them (F5.com has a dedicated solution). This will also require a solution for data replication between instances.

Sorry about the high-level answer, but it's hard to provide a more detailed one without knowing your particular needs and constraints. And even more important, why do you need to scale? Do you need more space, more throughput?

Comment: Updated with the constraints.
Can you give more specific answer ( As for load balancer, I  prefer app level driver  side round robin)

Comment: The best replication technology is Oracle's GoldenGate but it comes with a significant price tag. It has real-time replication capabilities, even on heterogeneous databases. Next best solution would be Oracle Data Integrator which has change data capture capabilities. Apart from these which come form Oracle, Talend has an integration tool with change data capture capabilities. If neither of these is an option, you can start developing an own replication solution (not advisable) using Oracle Streams or an Apache Kafka cluster.

Comment: Thanks for it, Can you put this as your answer.
It will help others, there are not many Q&A on the web for this.